# save the arguments in an array for each click of button

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have a

```
function value(num) {
  var numHolder = [];
  numHolder.push(num);
  console.log(num);
}
```

and I have button with different numbers each invoking the function with different arguments of each button. for example, number 1 button will invoke as

```
onclick="value(1)"
```

number 2 button will invoke as

```
onclick="value(2)"
```

how can I save these values inside the numHolder array without making the numHolder array global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an *IIFE* to create a closure

```
// `value` is initialised but undefined here (can be referenced because of `var`)
// ..
var value = (function (numHolder) { // IIFE creating closure
    return function (num) { // function expression to be assigned to `value`
        numHolder.push(num);
        console.log(num);
        // `numHolder` accessible here
    };
    // `numHolder` accessible here
}([])); // initial value for `numHolder`
// `value` is fully defined here
```